# Android Google Firestore - Listen Multiple Documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to listen multiple documents of Google Firestore at once.

Example: I have to listen the updates of documents A(id:1010), B(id:1020), and C(id:1030) only. All these documents have an ID field associated with them. I make my query like this.

```
 Query query = mCollectionReference.whereEqualTo("id", "1010");
 query = query.whereEqualTo("id", "1020");
 query = query.whereEqualTo("id", "1030");
 query.addSnapshotListener(this);
```

The problem here is, it doesn't listen to anything when I put multiple `whereEqualTo` condition, but for a single `whereEqualTo` it works fine.

So, is there any way to listen to multiple documents at once like using `whereEqualTo` with IDs in documents?

Any solution to read multiple documents is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there any way to listen to multiple documents at once like using whereEqualTo with IDs in documents?

No.  But you can use an ["in" query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) to specify multiple documents in an array, up to 10, to query or listen at the same time.  If you need more than 10, you will need multiple queries.

```
Query query = mCollectionReference
  .whereIn("id", Arrays.asList("1010", "1020")));
query.addSnapshotListener(this);
```